# How to show ui elements on top Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-container, unity-game-engine

how can I show my ui elements on top of the others ?

http://prntscr.com/brjccg you can see the right side of the panel but the left one is under the map object. How can fix that i want to see both sides of it ?

Here's the components it currently has on http://prntscr.com/brjdab

Comment: just literally move it on top.  drag it in the heirarchy.  note that it's totally ok to have **more than one canvas** - I always have many

Comment: http://prntscr.com/brjh5f still the same result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unity renders UI from top to bottom. Anything you want on top should be placed at last in hierarchy. This only works with UI elements. To change rendering order between 2D `Sprite` Objects and UI elements e.g Canvas, you can either change **Order in Layer** property of Sprite Renderer component or the same behaviour can be achieved by changing **Sort Order** property of Canvas. Object with greater value appears on top.

**Note:** You can also add new sorting layers using menu:

> Edit > Project Settings > Tags and Layers

Comment: Tried placing it above and also underneath and still no luck.

Comment: if you are using `sprite renderer` component for 2D map. try to change its order in layer and set it to negative value.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/brjl99 Now it appears on top of the map but the play is with negative value of order in layer but still appearing on top of the ui

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you are trying to say. What is still on top of UI?

Comment: The player * as you can see from the image.

Comment: you can also try by setting `Sort order` property to some positive value from `Canvas`.