# How do you sort UI elements in Canvas?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I don't get how you sort UI elements Z-index in Unity inside a Canvas, is it by hierarchy order ?
I'm trying to do a settings screen like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qNo1jloR_k

It's quite simple, you click on the button and it set the whole panel as first sibling in the hierarchy.

But this is what I get:
https://gyazo.com/cec14f21df2ded191875e6a8cfd9f124

Also, my gameplay panel had a red background, my graphics panel a green one, and my sound panel a yellow one.

I could avoid this problem by changing alpha on panels, but would like to make it work with z sorting... that I can't seem to understand on Unity.

Using unity 2017.1.2 and .NET 4.6 .

Comment: There's a related question here: [How to show ui elements on top Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38309945/5170571)

Comment: You missed a little point in the video: It's **no**t `SetAsFirstSibling` but **instead** `SetAsLastSibling` that is used. Still though, as in the answer of Zayed below, it's better to disable all tabs but the active one, especially if they have a lot of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **child** that is lower in the hierarchy is rendered on top of other ones.
Let's say there are 2 panels. panel1(red) and panel2(green).If the hierarchy is like this:
 -panel1
 -panel2
Then panel2 will be rendered on top of panel1. So, you'll see green panel.
Hope this answers your question.
Another suggestion, it is better to **deactivate** the unused panels and activate only the used panels. Because, if the unused panel is active, when it's not shown, it'll still take the processing power which is a waste. For example, if you have animation in the main menu, but currently you are showing the settings panel, your approach will keep the animations running in the main menu.